# Select As Status If Subtable Lines Include Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 Table named Order and OrderDetails

Order Table

```
    orderID   orderDate     OrderUserId
1    10       01.01.2010      .....
2    20       05.05.2011      .....
```

OrderDetails Table

```
 DetailID   OrderIdOfDetail  DetailProductID   DetailStatusID
1    25            10               xxx                1
2    26            10               xxx                2
3    27            10               xxx                2
4    28            10               xxx                0
5    29            10               xxx                1
6    30            20               xxx                1
7    31            20               xxx                2
8    32            20               xxx                0
```

DetailStatusId for closed , pending, cancelled bla...

For example I want to select orderID :  10.
If detail lines include DetailsStatusID 1 select order Status as "Pending".
If detail lines include DetailsStatusID 2 select order Status as "Open".
If all    DetailsStatusID is equal and  0 select order status as "Closed"

I tried "if exist" but couldn't  success.
How can I do it ?

Comment: So what would be the expected result from your sample data set for order id 10? Can you give more specific examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a `left join` to an derived table (subquery) that uses conditional aggregation to count the different `DetailStatusId`. This will also return a result of `Other` for `Status` if, for some reason, the `OrderId` has no corresponding details record.

```
select o.*
  , [Status]=case 
      when od.Status0 > 0 and od.Status0 = od.DetailCount 
        then 'Closed'
      when od.Status1 > 0
        then 'Pending'
      when od.Status2 > 0
        then 'Open'
      else 'Other'
      end
from orders as o
  left join (
    select 
        OrderIdOfDetail
      , DetailCount = count(*)
      , Status0 = sum(case when DetailStatusId = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
      , Status1 = sum(case when DetailStatusId = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
      , Status2 = sum(case when DetailStatusId = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
    from OrderDetails 
    group by OrderIdOfDetail
  ) as od 
    on o.OrderId = od.OrderIdOfDetail
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YPA79670

query results:

```
+---------+---------------------+-------------+---------+
| orderID |      orderDate      | OrderUserId | Status  |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+---------+
|      10 | 01.01.2010 00:00:00 |           1 | Pending |
|      20 | 05.05.2011 00:00:00 |           2 | Pending |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+---------+
```

subquery only results:

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| OrderIdOfDetail | DetailCount | Status0 | Status1 | Status2 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|              10 |           5 |       1 |       2 |       2 |
|              20 |           3 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Hello @SqlZim DetailCount always return 1.

Comment: @serdar I have added a rextester demo and included the results of the query and subquery. If `DetailCount` is always returning 1, then there is only 1 detail row for that `orderID`, or you might have accidentally changed the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you.Yes added other column names to group by.Because I got this error :  Column 'od.detailID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. :/ @SqlZim

Comment: @serdar That won't work, try looking at the demo again. You shouldn't be grouping by `od.detailID`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT o.orderID, 
       CASE 
          WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN DetailStatusID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN DetailStatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN DetailStatusID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
             THEN 'MultiStatus'
          WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN DetailStatusID = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Pending'
          WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN DetailStatusID = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Open'
          WHEN MAX(DetailStatusID) = 0 THEN 'Closed'
       END AS Status
FROM  Order AS o
JOIN OrderDetails AS od ON o.orderID = od.OrderIdOfDetail  
GROUP BY orderID
```

The query uses a `CASE` expression in order to calculate the `Status` field:

- It first checks whether the order contains *at least one* record with `DetailStatusID = 1`. If it does 'Pending' is returned.
- It then checks whether the order contains *at least one* record with `DetailStatusID = 2`. If it does 'Open' is returned.
- It then checks whether all records of the group have `DetailStatusID = 0`. In this case 'Closed' is returned. I assume that DetailStatusID cannot take negative vaues.

Comment: Thank you.But I want to learn that what if order contains both of DetailsStatusID = 1 DetailsStatusID = 2

Comment: @serdar This case is not covered in the requirements given in the OP. What do *you* want to happen in this case?

Comment: For example detail lines contains DetailStatusID  = 1 also DetailStatusID = 2 even DetailStatusID = 0 . In this case which status name will return ?

Comment: @serdar I do not know. You have to tell me because you know the actual requirements of your use case. What do you want to get as result in this case?

Comment: For example if detail lines contains DetailStatusID = 1 also DetailStatusID = 2 even DetailStatusID = 0 return as  'MultiStatus' Can I do it ?

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosBetsos.In fact I need one result,this returns multi results.But your answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, case when DetailStatusID = '1' then 'Pending'
               when DetailStatusID = '2' then 'Open'
               when DetailStatusID = '0' then 'Closed'
          end as OrderStatusDescription
From OrderDetails
Where OrderIdOfDetail = '10'
```

Comment: Adding an explanation why this solves the issue would improve your answer a lot.